# Removing lowest grade and averaging. C++, VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio, text-files, average

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I have been working on this code for some time, I need to remove the lowest grade (64) and then take the average and output the grade. My code works but my average isn't correct. it is supposed to be 90.09 and not 92.4. can someone look at my code and help me fix this?
The grades are as followed:96 86 88 95 88 92 77 80 95 64 100 94

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin;// declare an input file stream object fin
    fin.open("dat_hw5_prob1.txt");// opens a file
    if (fin.is_open())// check if file opened successfully
    {
        double total_score = 0, min_score, score, avg_score = 0; // initialize total score and avg score to 0

        int count = 0; // initialize number of scores to 0
        char letter_grade;

        while (fin >> score) {// read till the end of file
            count++; // increment number of scores
            fin >> score; // read a score from file

            // if this is the first score read or score read is less than minimum score, update minimum score
            if (count == 1 || (score < min_score))
            {
                min_score = score;
            }

            // add score to total score
            total_score += score;
        }

        // subtract minimum score from total score
        total_score -= min_score;
        count--; // decrement number of score by 1
        fin.close(); // close the file

        // if number of score > 0
        if (count > 0)
            avg_score = (total_score) / count; // calculate average score

        // determine final grade based on average score
        if (avg_score >= 90)
            letter_grade = 'A';
        else if (avg_score >= 80)
            letter_grade = 'B';
        else if (avg_score >= 70)
            letter_grade = 'C';
        else
            letter_grade = 'D';

        // display the average score and final grade
        cout << "Average score: " << avg_score << " final grade: " << letter_grade << endl;
    }
    else // file open failure
        cout << "Unable to open file: dat_hw5_prob1.txt" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In this line:**

```
 while (fin >> score){
```

You read the next `score` from the file.
But **2 lines afterwards** after incrementing `count` you **read another** `score` with:

```
fin >> score;
```

This line is overriding the value just read from the file (in the `while(...)`), causing you to actually **skip** the 1st, 3rd, 5th etc. scores.
You can observe it if you add a `std::cout << score << std::endl;` before accumulating the score.

**In order to solve it simply remove that second read.**

Comment: WOW , I didn't realize I repeated. Thank you again!!